# Header Layout Hidden When Scrolling With Soft Keyboard Shown

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I have a strange error with ScrollView.

When the soft keyboard is not shown, scrolling works fine on both 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0.
But when the soft keyboard is shown, scrolling makes header layout invisible on 2.2 and 2.3.

What's wrong with my layout?
Please give me your suggestion.

This is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/b2u_header" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/msg_register"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/friend_name_table"
            layout="@layout/b2u_profile_friend_name_table" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/other_info"
            layout="@layout/b2u_profile_settings_other_info" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/password"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:hint="パスワード"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_password_rewrite"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:hint="確認用パスワード"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="■パスワードを忘れた時のヒント"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_reminder_questions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/reminder_questions" >
        </Spinner>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="こたえ"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/answer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="■ メールマガジンを受け取る"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/confirmemail_group"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_notreceive"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="受け取らない"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_receive"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="受け取る"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_agree_term"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="■ 利用規約、プライバシーポリシーの同意"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/term_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/agree_term"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" 同意する" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```